# How to fix TypeError: too many positional arguments when using make_pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn

For some reason I'm getting a TypeError in the following code.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import validation_curve

def PolynomialRegression(degree=2, **kwargs):
     return make_pipeline(PolynomialFeatures(degree), LinearRegression(**kwargs))

train_score, val_score = validation_curve(PolynomialRegression(), X, y,
                                      'polynomialfeatures__degree',
                                      degree, cv=7)
```

> File ~/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/inspect.py:3108, in Signature._bind(self, args, kwargs, partial)
> 3104 else:
> 3105     if param.kind in (_VAR_KEYWORD, _KEYWORD_ONLY):
> 3106         # Looks like we have no parameter for this positional
> 3107         # argument
> -> 3108         raise TypeError(
> 3109             'too many positional arguments') from None
> 3111     if param.kind == _VAR_POSITIONAL:
> 3112         # We have an '*args'-like argument, let's fill it with
> 3113         # all positional arguments we have left and move on to
> 3114         # the next phase
> 3115         values = [arg_val]

TypeError: too many positional arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you shared seems to have a small error. The `degree` parameter in the `validation_curve` function should be passed as a range or array of values, not as a single value.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import validation_curve

def PolynomialRegression(degree=2, **kwargs):
    return make_pipeline(PolynomialFeatures(degree), LinearRegression(**kwargs))

degrees = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  # Example degrees for the validation curve

train_score, val_score = validation_curve(
    PolynomialRegression(), X, y,
    param_name='polynomialfeatures__degree',
    param_range=degrees,
    cv=7
)
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. 
I had defined 'degree' twice before and this fixed it